# What Is The Preferred Syntax For Creating A Trigger - Why Isn't This Working?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

this is probably a simple enough error but because I'm new to sql it's taking me quite a while to figure out what it is. Any suggestions would be appreciated. The error is near 'INSERT INTO Changed_Prices(model, GETDATE(), OLD.price, NEW.price)' at line 3.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER PcPriceUpdate 
BEFORE INSERT ON pcs
INSERT INTO Changed_Prices(model, GETDATE(), OLD.price, NEW.price);
//

DELIMITER//
CREATE TRIGGER LaptopPriceUpdate 
BEFORE INSERT ON laptops
INSERT INTO Changed_Prices(model, GETDATE(), OLD.price, NEW.price);
//

DELIMITER//
CREATE TRIGGER PrintersPriceUpdate 
BEFORE INSERT ON printers
INSERT INTO Changed_Prices(model, GETDATE(), OLD.price, NEW.price);
//
```

Comment: `GETDATE()` is SQL Server code.  Use `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`.

Comment: Still not working I'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html) or [examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) and try spotting what's missing :)

Comment: Remove all DELIMITER statements and `//` chars. Specify where `model` must be taken from (for example, it can be `NEW.model`).

Comment: Still getting it, i'm afraid.